# Nearest neighbour distance in Graphene

Tags: condensed-matter, graphene

The lattice spacing in Graphene (Honeycomb Lattice) is 2.46Å. So, this should be the nearest neighbour distance in graphene. But I found it to be 1.42Å in [this website](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Fig-S7-Pair-distances-in-graphene-lattice-Three-nearest-neighbor-pair-distances-in-the_fig10_340022062#:%7E:text=Three%20nearest%20neighbor%20pair%20distances,%2C%202.46%20%C3%85%2C%202.84%20%C3%85.). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm guessing the lattice spacing is the distance between the centers of neighboring hexagons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphene primitive unit cell has two atoms in it, not just one. This is necessary because the honeycomb lattice is not one of the Bravais lattices. Because of that, the nearest neighbour is within the cell and not as far apart as the lattice parameter says it is.